# Porque o texto está fora de linha? e como solucionar no bootstrap 4?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, layout-responsivo

Continuando a minha [pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/411401/problemas-em-responsividade-do-bootstrap-em-inputs-labels-e-selects) feita anteriormente, estou utilizando agora o seguinte [código](https://www.bootply.com/arthurabi1515/UTgRK5DuZ7). Ocorreu outro problema simples que não estou conseguindo resolver. O texto escrito "LIMPAR FILTROS" fica desajustado referente a um botão. Abaixo está em imagem o problema.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O texto "LIMPAR FILTROS" está passando  a fora do botão. Toda vez que redimensiono ao minimo antes dos *inputs, labels e selects* ficare, sobrepostos, esse texto não fica fixado ao botão.

Porém não sei como prosseguir para deixar esse texto de forma responsiva, meu objetivo é que quando redimensiono ao minimo antes da sobreposição, o texto "LIMPAR FILTROS" diminua de tamanho ou o botão aumente seu tamanho para prosseguir junto ao texto.

O que está acontecendo nesse caso e como posso solucionar esse problema?

> Ao fazer um teste, até os icones do span ficam desajustados, assim que for tentando redimensionar até o minimo possivel, antés que tudo fique sobreposto.

Comment: Esse campo deve ter alguma largura fixa. Já inspecionou o elemento e viu o código CSS? Se puder postar o código como HTML aqui, será de grande ajuda.

Comment: o codigo se encontra aqui https://www.bootply.com/arthurabi1515/UTgRK5DuZ7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coloca um `min-width` no botão que seja do tamanho suficiente para caber o texto todo. Eu usei 170px e funcionou bem para telas de até 272px de largura.

No seu CSS coloque algo como o CSS abaixo e no HTML coloque `class="limpar"` no seu btn

```
button.limpar {
    min-width: 170px;
}
```

Veja como fica

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: acabo de verificar que cometi um erro, eu não atualizei o meu bootply com o código corrigido da pergunta anterior que tu me ajudou. Agora esta atualizado. Se puder me ajudar agradeço. Me desculpe por esse transtorno.

Comment: @ArthurAbitante cara testa com esse código veja se t eatende https://codepen.io/hugocsl/pen/dybQxNJ

Comment: No código que tu enviou, parece ainda estar desajustado, passei para o bootply funcionou direitinho. Fiz o teste colocando no meu sistema e ficou 
 algo estranho, está tudo em cima do outro, tipo os labels estão no mesmo lugar, na mesma posição.

Comment: Estou tentando ver no meu sistema aonde está sendo incluida a biblioteca do bootstrap pra ver se não é algo referente a versão

Comment: @ArthurAbitante o que ocorre eh que com col-12 col-md-2 a coluna fica com tamanho fixo, ao fica bom se usar apenas Col no grid. Ai pra colocar os campos um abaixo do outro eu coloque a classe flex-column na Row, como vc pode ver nesse link do Codepen que citei acima

Comment: gostaria de deixar uma colocação também, acabo de perceber que dependendo do versionamento, da erro no bootstrap. Estou utilizando a versão 4.1.2 do bootstrap e usando esse metodo não está funcionando como deve. Porém mudando a versão para 4.3.1. Novamente muito obrigado por sua ajuda, solucionou muito bem meu problema, muito obrigado

Comment: @ArthurAbitante legal que resolveu então! Tmj 